# How to manually change diverging colors in leaflet map/R?

Tags: r, plot, leaflet

I have produced a map of Denmark

```
library(leaflet.extras)
library(leaflet)

#Data

folk1 <- readr::read_csv2("http://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/folk1a/CSV?OMR%C3%85DE=*")


municipalityDK("INDHOLD","OMRÅDE",data=folk1,legend=T,pal = "GnBu") %>%
  setMapWidgetStyle(list(background= "white"))
```

Which looks like:

[image]

However, I have not succeeded in finding a color palette that visualizes data the way I prefer. I have used those listed [here](https://github.com/mikkelkrogsholm/leafletDK).

I would like the color palette to look like this:

[image]

Can this be done manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom palette with `RColorBrewer`:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("#2C77BF", "red"))
```

Then include your custom palette and number of selected colors in your map:

```
municipalityDK("INDHOLD","OMRÅDE",data=folk1,legend=T,pal = colfunc(10)) %>%
  setMapWidgetStyle(list(background= "white"))
```

**Map**

[image: map]

Comment: Perfect, thank you @Ben. That did exactly what I requested. Please, can you elaborate what "10" indicates in `colfunc(10)`? Simply for my own learning.

Comment: Great - glad this helped. `colfunc` is actually a function created by `colorRampPalette`. The number (an integer) fed into `colfunc` will return that many colors in the palette using the custom function (in this case, 10 colors are returned). You can change this number and see what results you get. Note, you can use more than 2 colors with `colorRampPalette`. And, to see all the built in palettes, you can enter `display.brewer.all()`.